# Do I need multiple classes to make a poker program with 1 user?

Tags: java

I am working on a poker program. It should deal 5 cards, allow the user to replace up to 3 cards. and then it will evaluate the hand and give points for the different hands, ex: a pair = 1 point, 2 pair = 2 points etc.

I have written out a basic outline of how I think it should go, but I am really struggling with actually putting it in to code. I just have a couple of questions to help get me started

Do I need to do multiple classes, EX: a deck class, a card class, a hand class? Or can I just do a poker class and just have separate methods?

Here is what I have so far.

Next I am thinking I can make

```
public class Poker 
{
    private int rank, suit;

    private static String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    private static String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                   "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, or if this is even a good start? Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't *need* multiple classes, but it's good practice.

Comment: thanks. So far I have only ever used one class. Well two, but the second always just contained my main to run the other class

Comment: You should use multiple classes if and only if they make your program better. Where better means "easier to write", "easier to read", "easier to change in the future", etc.

Comment: Your ideal design would achieve [high cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) and [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)) of your classes.  Though your task is extra trivial you can nevertheless think about it in OO way. You may decide to implement `Player` and `Dealer` as separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should absolutely use multiple classes.

The idea of separating code into different classes isn't about how much code you're going to write, it's about what makes sense. In an object oriented language like Java, you want to separate logic belonging to card evaluation from logic belonging to shuffling a deck from logic belonging to regular game flow, etc.

I'm not going to give you an outline of how you should write this program, because that'd take too long, and besides, it really depends on your style of coding the choices you make while you write, but to start off, here are some ideas:

1. I would replace the String arrays you made with enums, and give the "two, three, ..." enum numeric value as well to make it easier to evaluate hand strengths.
2. I would create a card class which holds both a value and suit enum
3. I would create a deck enum which holds a list of cards and knows how to shuffle them
4. I would create a hand evaluator which accepts a list, where each item in the list contains 5 cards, and then sorts them from the strongest hand to the weakest.

I've created poker games several times in the past (texas holdem). It's not a simple coding exercise which can easily be done by writing a few methods, it's definitely a challenge, and you should structure your code nicely to make development more intuitive.

**Edit:**

I would also make the Card class implement Comparable. Being able to sort cards in a hand from weakest card to strongest will make it a lot easier to evaluate the overall hand's strength.